# What is the theoretical geometry of bubble universes?

Tags: string-theory, cosmology, astrophysics, universe, multiverse

My research has led me to look into the idea of bubble universes which I don't know very much about.  The first thing that I am looking for is understanding or visualising how could many bubbles co-exist geometrically, assuming each bubble universe is like ours (that is, a flat euclidean geometry). Are we talking about an n-manifold that has multiple bubbles embedded in it? Submanifolds? Or can we extend the idea of branes to the notion of bubbles? Is it perhaps a 3-sphere that houses multiple 2-spheres? Put simply, what is the theoretical geometry that engulfs all the bubbles and how would they be connected?

Comment: You do understand that our universe does not have a flat, Euclidean geometry, right?

Comment: I meant to say that the curvature of the universe appears to be flat (or near flat) from a number of observations, but yes, it is a 4 dimensional spacetime universe that can be  represented as a simple manifold.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a Euclidean and a Lorentzian manifold?

Comment: Luis another way of putting @Danu's question is do you understand the nontrivial signature of the metric, i.e. we're dealing with a **pseudo**-Riemannian manifold. However, your question bespeaks a mathematics background, so I'm guessing you do, so are you asking about *sections* of spacetime? Otherwise, I think this is a perfectly good question, asking for a quick overview of global topology, and you want info on things like whether the bubbles are held to be topological embeddings / immersions and so on. Am I right? (not my field, so I won't answer - trying to improve the question)

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot :), +1 for the question BTW, I hope it gets an answer because I'd like to see one.

Comment: Yes precisely, and I thank you for articulating the problem. I will admit that although I know the difference between Euclidean and Lorentzian, I have not studied the Lorentzian manifolds in any depth or complex n-manifolds as of yet.  But yes, the issue still begs the question of what is the global geometry/topology that would be capable to encapsulate the bubbles.